# How to add these constraints to Django models?

Tags: django, django-models, constraints, unique-constraint

Help me please.  How to make constraints in the database?

I am using sqlite, django 3.2, python 3.7

I have three models: Refbook, Versions of refbooks, Elements of refbook

```
from django.db import models

class Refbook(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField()   


class VersionRefbook(models.Model):
    refbook_id = models.ForeignKey('Refbook',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='versions')
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('refbook_id', 'version')


class Element(models.Model):
    version_id = models.ManyToManyField('VersionRefbook')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

The following constraints must be added to these models:

1. **There cannot be more than one Refbook with the same value in the "code" field.**
2. **There cannot be more than one Version with the same set of values "refbook id" and "version"**
3. **One Refbook cannot have more than one Version with the same date**
4. **In one Version of refbook, there cannot be more than one Element of refbook with the same value in the "code" field**

1. OK. I solved the first point by adding the «unique=true» parameter to the «code» field in the Refbook class.
2. It seems that I solved the seconf point by adding the «unique_together = ('refbook_id', 'version')» parameter to the Meta class.
3. Third point. I think need to override the save method. But how? And is it right?
4. Fourth point. I wanted to add a parameter « unique_together = ('version_id', 'code')» to the Meta class of the Element class, but there is a connection ManyToMany there. It gives an error message.

Have I added the first and second constraints correctly? And how to solve the third and fourth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have added the first two constraints correctly.

**3. One Refbook cannot have more than one Version with the same date**

Just add another unique constraint for version and date.

```
class VersionRefbook(models.Model):
    refbook_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Refbook',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='versions'
    )
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('refbook_id', 'version')
        unique_together = ('version', 'date')
```

**4. In one Version of refbook, there cannot be more than one Element of refbook with the same value in the "code" field**

One solution could be to use intermediate model:

```
class Element(models.Model):
    version_id = models.ManyToManyField(
        'VersionRefbook',
        through='ElementVersionRefbook'
    )
    value = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class ElementVersionRefbook(models.Model):
    version = models.ForeignKey(VersionRefbook, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    element = models.ForeignKey(Element, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('version', 'code')
```

You can create instances as below:

```
elem = Element.objects.create(value='some value')
refbook = Refbook.objects.create(
    code='some code',
    name='some name',
    description='some desc'
)
version = VersionRefbook.objects.create(
    refbook_id=refbook,
    version='1.0',
    date='2023-01-01'
)
elem_version_refbook = ElementVersionRefbook.objects.create(
    version=version,
    element=elem,
    code='123'
)
elem_version_refbook = ElementVersionRefbook.objects.create(
    version=version,
    element=elem,
    code='345'
)
```

If you try to add `ElementRefbook` entry with same version and code as below, it will raise `IntegrityError`

```
elem_version_refbook = ElementVersionRefbook.objects.create(
    version=version,
    element=elem,
    code='123'
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will now test this solution. If I use a intermediate model, is there any specifics about creating instances?

Comment: I have added specifics for creating instances.

Comment: Thanks! I have corrected  class Meta  to   unique_together =[['refbook_id', 'version'], ['version', 'date']]. Otherwise one of unique_together didn't work.